# How to get a value from the column inside of the Kendo.Grid's editor's template on focus out or onblur()?

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I have the following html generated for my grid:

[image]

The grid has an editor template. So, every time I click on the column, it changes to an edit mode and allows me to change the value in the textbox.

How can I get the value `$50.00` with a jquery on blur or lost focus event?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [blur event](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) or [focusout event](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/) I suggest to use [mouseout event](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/).

You can delegate the event to the td using [:nth-child() selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

In the following example I address the unit price column with:

```
$('#grid').on('mouseout', 'tbody[role="rowgroup"] tr[role="row"] td[role="gridcell"]:nth-child(3)', function(e) {
    var val = $(this).text();
    console.log(val);
})
```

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products",
                dataType: "jsonp"
            }
        },
        pageSize: 5,
        group: {
            field: "UnitsInStock",
            dir: "asc"
        }
    },
    selectable: "multiple row",
    pageable: {
        buttonCount: 5
    },
    scrollable: true,
    groupable: true,
    columns: [
        {
            field: "ProductName",
            title: "Product Name"
        },
        {
            field: "UnitPrice",
            title: "Unit Price",
            format: "{0:c}"
        },
        {
            field: "UnitsInStock",
            title: "Units In Stock"
        }
    ],
    excelExport: function (e) {
        e.workbook.fileName = $("#fileName").val();
    }
});
$('#grid').on('mouseout', 'tbody[role="rowgroup"] tr[role="row"] td[role="gridcell"]:nth-child(3)', function(e) {
    var val = $(this).text();
    console.log(val);
})
```

```css
#selectRow {
    width: 75px;
}

#groupRow {
    width: 145px;
}

#colIndex,
#colWidth {
    width: 110px;
}

#fileName {
    width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


<div id="example">
    <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention that the cell has an editor template. So, everytime I click on that it allows me to edit the number. So, I want to capture new number

Comment: Please,  add the js and html. Not the rendered html.